# Wait for configuration to be loaded

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, configuration

For the vue application I'm working on, I'd like to have a configuration file, which can be edited after having built it.

For this I imagined putting a json configuration file in the public area of my frontend. config.json:

```
{
    "apiUrl": "https://localhost:44336/"
}
```

Have a service exposing the configuration values. configuration.service.ts:

```
class ConfigurationService {
    public apiUrl: string | undefined;

    public constructor() {
        fetch("config.json")
            .then(response => {
                return response.json()
            })
            .then(data => {
                this.setApiUrl(data["apiUrl"])
            })
            .catch(err => {
                // TODO: handle error
            })
    }

    private setApiUrl(apiUrl: string){
        this.apiUrl = apiUrl
    }
}

export const configurationService = new ConfigurationService()
```

And use it where I need it by letting the framework do the instantiation. axios.helper.ts:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import { configurationService } from '@/_services/configuration.service'

function configureDefaults() {
  axios.defaults.baseURL = configurationService.apiUrl
}
```

Now I've got a race condition, where the configuration is ready only after the value has already been used.

How can this be properly handled?

I haven't found a clean possibility to wait for the initialization to finish in the constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the 'proper' way to do this, but I've added the config value to a meta tag in the head of index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta id="apiUrl" content="https://localhost:44336/" />
  [...]
</head>

<body>
  [...]
</body>

</html>
```

And read it in the configuration service:

```
class ConfigurationService {
  public apiUrl: string | undefined;

  public constructor() {
    var configElement = document.getElementById('apiUrl')

    if (configElement !== null) {
      var apiUrlValue = configElement.getAttribute('content')
      this.apiUrl = apiUrlValue !== null ? apiUrlValue : undefined
    }
  }
}

export const configurationService = new ConfigurationService()
```